# Trouble with query, execute non scalar not behaving as I thought

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm having trouble with a SQL query:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=user;" + "password=pass;" + "server=server;" + "database=db;"))
{
   using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CompaniesDB].[dbo].[Companies] WHERE BolagsID = '" + BolagsID + "'"))
   {
      conn.Open();
      comm.Connection = conn;
      MessageBox.Show("TEST: {0}", Convert.ToString((int)comm.ExecuteScalar()));
   }
}
```

I'm expecting to get an int in the message box conveying the number of rows that `BolagsID` occurs in. But I get 0 every time. I've tried the query in SQL Server Management Studio and it works fine there. What am I doing wrong/missing?

EDIT:

This works, but now I don't know how to parameterize the values:

```
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CompaniesDB].[dbo].[Companies] WHERE BolagsID = " + BolagsID;

ADODB.Connection conn2 = new ADODB.Connection();
ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();

string strConn = "Provider=...;Data Source=...;Database=...;User Id=...;Password=...";

conn2.Open(strConn);

rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic;
rs.Open(query, conn2);

if (rs.Fields[0].Value > 0)
...stuff...
```

Comment: First thing to fix: use parameterized SQL instead of including the value within the SQL itself.

Comment: Did you fill the database?

Comment: Is BolagsID a string or int in the database? If it's an int don't put the single quotes around it.
You might also want to take the actual text that's in the Sql Command and run that in SMS. Or use profiler and see what's actually sent to the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot of stuff before trying out a whole different approach. This gives me the result I want:

```
string query = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CompaniesDB].[dbo].[Companies] WHERE BolagsID = " + BolagsID;

ADODB.Connection conn2 = new ADODB.Connection();
ADODB.Recordset rs = new ADODB.Recordset();

string strConn = "Provider=...;Data Source=...;Database=...;User Id=...;Password=...";

conn2.Open(strConn);

rs.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenStatic;
rs.Open(query, conn2);

if (rs.Fields[0].Value > 0)
...stuff...
```

Note that both connection and record set are closed outside of this code snippet.

Comment: I know that using un-parameterized variables is a really bad practise, but I don't know how to incorporate that in this. Also, the MVC site which this belongs to has some sort of validation for the field which handles that particular input. I tried to do some sql injection but wasn't able to do to constraints in the MVC application. So, even though it is bad practise, it should be safe in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Like others are saying, parameters are a good idea. Here's something to get you started:

```
string query = @"SELECT Count(*) FROM [CompaniesDB].[dbo].[Companies] WHERE BolagsID = @BolagsID";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@BolagsID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = BolagsID;
    conn.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("TEST: {0}", Convert.ToString((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
    conn.Close();
}
```

Basically a 0 is returned if there is an error in your query, so even though SSMS is smart enough to resolve it, the sql command isn't.

A quick way to make sure that everything else is working okay is to change the query to just "SELECT Count(*) FROM [CompaniesDB].[dbo].[Companies]". If that doesn't work then the issue could lie with your database connection (permissions?) or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CompaniesDB].[dbo].[Companies] WHERE BolagsID = '" + BolagsID + "'" to a string str as follows

```
string str =@"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [CompaniesDB].[dbo].[Companies] WHERE BolagsID = '" + BolagsID + "'";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("user id=user;" + "password=pass;" + "server=server;" + "database=db;"))
{
   using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(str))
   {
      conn.Open();
      comm.Connection = conn;
      MessageBox.Show("TEST: {0}", Convert.ToString((int)comm.ExecuteScalar()));
   }
}
```

Then do a watch/quickwatch on str's value to get the exact query that is getting run and then run the same query in Sql Managment studio. If you get 0 in Sql Management Studio as well, then the problem is that the data is just not there.

Comment: From my understanding, everything will be disposed in a using block. Please correct me if i'm wrong. Should be no need for double usings except if you want junior members to understand you better. Curious to know if I am right or wrong...

Comment: Probably. :). I was just re-using what the questioner had initially typed out. Feel free to up-vote my answer if it is a good one :)

Comment: And the answer to your(@andrew-jansen) question is no, everything wont be disposed in using block. Because using is a syntactic sugar for try catch finally as mentioned here. SO if you just put SqlConnection conn in using but not Sqlcommand, then SqlCommand will not get disposed the way conn gets disposed.

Comment: Oops missed the link for how using translates into try and finally block. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C